# What is the antonym of shadow [i.e. the shadow-casting object]?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for a more concise expression for a shadow-casting object in contrast to the shadow itself. Is there a generalisable term for something that casts a shadow?

Comment: A shadow is caused by an ***obstruction*** in the path of light.

Comment: It's not an antonym of *shadow* but a causative agent.

Comment: An object casting a shadow is what it is; I don't think there is a general name for them.

Comment: @Spagirl By all means, please do.

Comment: Similar (but more about people, maybe): [Word for a shadow's owner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364936)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an object whose specific purpose is to cast a shadow, but only in a very explicit circumstance. That is the part of a sundial whose shadow lets you read the time and is called a '***gnomon***'.  Per the OED:

> a.    A pillar, rod, or other object which serves to indicate the time of
>   day by casting its shadow upon a marked surface; esp. the pin or
>   triangular plate used for this purpose in an ordinary sun-dial.

One could use 'gnomon' figuratively or poetically for casters of other shadows.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "**caster**" (as in **shadow-caster**) which is defined by Collins English Dictionary (via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/caster) as:

> 1. a person or thing that casts

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shadow+caster%2Cshadow-caster%2C+caster+of+shadows&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshadow%20caster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshadow%20-%20caster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaster%20of%20shadows%3B%2Cc0) shows that shadow-caster is currently slightly more in use than "caster of shadows"

So, as a generic example, you could say "I walked among the casters of shadows" or "I walked among the shadow-casters". But this example sounds a little contrived. I found it difficult to come up with an example where a generic term was required. It might be easier just to refer to the objects as whatever they are (as suggested in the comments).

Interestingly, there is also ["Implicit processing of shadows"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698901001419). It's in an academic journal and might be behind a paywall, but in summary it differentiates between **cast** shadows and **attached** shadows. A cast shadow is where an object blocks the path of light. An attached shadow is where a particular surface faces away from the light.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind obsolete, yet still understandable by the erudite, 'inumbration' is the noun. The verb, 'inumbrate', is the source of the noun, and might prove useful as well.

From [*OED*](http://oed.com/):

> **† inˈumbrate**, *v.*
>   .... 
>   *trans.* To cast a shadow upon; to shade; to overshadow, put in the shade.
>   .... 
>   **† inumˈbration** *n. Obsolete* overshadowing, shading.

To judge by the *OED* attestations, the verb has not been in use since the 19th century, and the noun since the 17th.

For a term in contemporary use, albeit rare, [*OED*](http://oed.com/) attests 'overshadower' as recently as 2002 in an entry updated for the Third Edition, December 2004:

> A person who or thing which overshadows.

The 'overshadower' is distinct as a matter of comparative degree from the 'shadower':

> One who or something which shadows....
>
> ([*OED*](http://oed.com/), excerpt from definition **1a** of **shadower**, *n.*)

The *OED* entry for 'shadower', first published in 1913, "has not yet been fully updated".

Answer (score -3):

There is no antonym for the shadow.

For an object to cast a shadow it has to be **opaque **. An opaque object cast a shadow, but a transparent object like glass can't cast a shadow.

A shadow casting object is an **Opaque Object**.

Good to know information:

Secondly,  when object (or a subject) itself is depicted as shadow  (especially in art) they are called **Silhouette**.

Note: translucent object also cast partial shadow.

Comment: enlighten me, where I am wrong.